# Change the reference folder using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

In the folder reference given below, I need to change the folder reference to the previous folder. I tried using regex. But it ain't worked.

```
var str = "../../myfolder is my folder xxx ../myfolder is also my folder and ../../../myfolder this is too";
```

Expected result:

```
str = "../myfolder is my folder xxx myfolder is also my folder and ../../myfolder this is too";
```

Comment: `str.replace("../", "")`, `str0.replace("../", "")`, `str1.replace("../", "")`

Comment: oh sorry forget to say one thing..i will change the question correcly now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
str.split(/\.\.\/\b/g).join("");
```

**DEMO**

```js
var str = "../../myfolder is my folder ../myfolder is also my folder and ../../../myfolder this is too";

console.log(str.split(/\.\.\/\b/g).join(""));
```